# Strange behavior of java Simple Date format

Tags: java

I want to get "month-year" from timeStamp so using this date for-matter
but seeing strange behaviour.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-YY");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(1451197799000L));
```

The output i get from this is

```
from 01 to 26-12-2015 (ts : 1451111399000) = Dec-15

from 27-12-2015 (ts : 1451197799000L ) to 31-12-2015 = Dec-16
```

I don't know why it is happening

Comment: Use `yy` for the year part .

Comment: This can happen during the last week of the year or the first week of the year as capital `Y` stands for [week year](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for the date and time letter patterns.

You have put "YY" for year when what you actually want is "yy".